# Best technique for saving and syncing binary data offline in iOS?

Tags: ios, firebase, offline, firebase-storage

I am working on an app that collects user data including photos. It's mandated that this app should work in offline mode - meaning that the user can complete surveys and take photos without an internet connection and that data should sync back to a remote database. How is this generally handled? Do I create a local database with `Core Data` and write an additional layer to manage saving/reading from a server? Are there any frameworks that help facilitate that syncing?

I have also been looking into backend services such as `Firebase` that include `iOS SDKs` that appear to handle a lot of the heavy lifting of offline support, but it does not appear to support offline syncing of image files through the `Firebase Storage SDK`.

Can anyone recommend the least painful way to handle this?

Answer (score 0):

Couchbase Mobile / Couchbase Lite is probably the best solution I've come across so far.

It allows offline data storage including binary data, and online syncing with a CouchDB compatible server. It works best with their Couchbase Server / Sync Gateway combination, but if you don't need to use filtered replication or 'channels' (e.g. for syncing data specific to a single user with a shared database), you can use Cloudant which saves you having to set up your own server.

Its also available across most platforms.

Answer (score -1):

Generally for images it is best to use NSFileManager and save your images in either the documents directory or the caches directory depending on the types of images you are storing.  Core Data or Firebase are databases that are more qualified for data than images although they do support arbitrary data storage.

You can also try SDWebImage which has a lot of features around loading and storing images.